# How to solve this problem? Would coordinate compression work?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, coordinates, rectangles

You have a 1000 x 1000 2D grid, and are given coordinates for N rectangles (1 <= N <= 10^5), which have sides parallel to coordinate axes. Coordinates are given as (x_1, y_1) by (x_2, y_2).
You also have the integer K (1 <= K <= 10^5), and the problem is to determine how much area of the grid is overlapped by K rectangles.

I want to use coordinate compression to solve this problem (though I don't think it will be of much help), and while I wanted to store data for every coordinate unit square, I think it would take too much time. Also since these rectangles are drawn on a 2D grid, I don't know how to scan through the coordinates or sort them.

Comment: Is K the same as N? (Typo?)

Comment: As @MinosIllyrien pointed out, the purpose of `K` is unclear. Do you need to find `K` of the `N` rectangles that maximize the covered area? Regardless, reading about the [sweep line algorithm](http://tryalgo.org/en/geometry/2016/06/25/union-of-rectangles/) should get you started!